# VBA unavailable from Office programs

Tags: vba, microsoft-office, microsoft-office-2010, avira

I recently reinstalled Windows 10, Avira Free Antivirus v. 15.0.44.142, and Office Professional Plus 2010. Before the reinstallation, this combination of applications worked fine.

Now, when I try to open the VBA IDE from a new Word document, I get the following message:

> Word has encountered a problem.
>
> There is a problem saving the file.

with some possible causes listed underneath, such as missing disk space, low RAM, or missing permissions; none of which are relevant.

The only thing that might be relevant is:

> This error can also occur if the computer is running a version of antivirus software that is incompatible with the Microsoft Office or must be updated.

As noted, I am running Avira Free Antivirus, and AFAICT the antivirus is updated. I tried opening the VBA IDE while Avira real-time protection was turned off, but without success.

Once I dismiss the message, the VBA IDE window opens, but there is no available project, and most of the menu items are disabled.

Saving a document with the `.docm` extension before opening the VBA IDE doesn't help.

There are comparable odd results when trying to open the VBA IDE from other applications:

- Excel lists three projects **Project1**, **Project2** and **Project3**, but without the usual tree of objects underneath each project -- class modules, standard modules etc -- and without the ThisWorkbook node.
- PowerPoint does the same as Word -- no project at all -- but without any error.

I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling VBA via the Office installer.

Security settings are set to disable macros with a warning. IIRC the old behavior was to disable macros unless I explicitly allowed them for the specific document. **Trust the object model** for each application is checked.

I've looked for a setting to control this in Avira, with no success.

The registry doesn't contain the `VBAOff` key described [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/281954/how-to-turn-off-visual-basic-for-applications-when-you-deploy-office).

**How can I enable VBA for the Office applications?**

NB. The previous installation wasn't a clean install of Windows 10; it was first Windows 8, then 8.1, then 10.

Things I have tried before opening the VBA editor:

- Repair Office
- Uninstall and reinstall Office, then manually install Office 2010 SP2
- Windows update (only found Office updates after the aforemnetioned manual installation)
- Running Word with administrator permissions
- **Enable all macros** selected from the Trust Center
- Deleting the `Normal.dotm` template and allowing Word to recreate it
- Uninstalling Office, running the "Clean Office uninstall" tool referenced by @harrymc in the comments, and reinstalling Office
- Adding Outlook (which was previously not installed)
- Turning off UAC (before starting Word)
- Booting in Safe Mode -- I was unable to start Word; Word wasn't recognized as activated
- Setting `HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\FileSystem LongPathsEnabled = 1`, and rebooting

---

Looking at the Event Viewer, I didn't find anything in **System**, **Application** or **Security** (all under **Windows Logs**). The only thing I did find was the following event in **Applications and Services Logs -> Microsoft Office Alerts** every time I try to open the VBA editor in Word on a new document:

```
Log Name:      OAlerts
Source:        Microsoft Office 14 Alerts
Date:          07/03/2019 20:49:42
Event ID:      300
Task Category: None
Level:         Information
Keywords:      Classic
User:          N/A
Description:
Microsoft Word
Word has encountered a problem.
P1: 200815
P2: 14.0.7015.1000
P3: 5v59
P4: 0x80070002

Event Xml:
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
  <System>
    <Provider Name="Microsoft Office 14 Alerts" />
    <EventID Qualifiers="0">300</EventID>
    <Level>4</Level>
    <Task>0</Task>
    <Keywords>0x80000000000000</Keywords>
    <TimeCreated SystemTime="2019-03-07T18:49:42.772417400Z" />
    <EventRecordID>120</EventRecordID>
    <Channel>OAlerts</Channel>
    <Security />
  </System>
  <EventData>
    <Data>Microsoft Word</Data>
    <Data>Word has encountered a problem.</Data>
    <Data>200815</Data>
    <Data>14.0.7015.1000</Data>
    <Data>5v59</Data>
    <Data>0x80070002</Data>
  </EventData>
</Event>
```

There is no similar event when opening the editor in Excel or PowerPoint.

---

Using Sysinternals ProcMon, capturing only while trying to open the VBA editor from Word, and filtering the results for `Process Name = "WINWORD.EXE"` and excluding `SUCCESS`, `BUFFER OVERFLOW` and `NAME NOT FOUND` from `Result`, I found the following:

```
RegOpenKey         ACCESS DENIED      
      HKLM\Software\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\VBA
CreateFileMapping  FILE LOCKED WITH READERS
      C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\microsoft shared\VBA\VBA7\VBE7.DLL
CreateFileMapping  FILE LOCKED WITH READERS
      C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\microsoft shared\VBA\VBA6\VBE6EXT.OLB
```

The `FILE LOCKED WITH READERS` repeats a number of times.

But on further investigation, I see that later reads from the same registry key (`HKLM\Software\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\VBA`) succeed. Also, the `CreateFileMapping` is using the long name of the path; which is immediately followed by a successful `CreateFileMapping` using the DOS name, e.g. `C:\PROGRA~2\COMMON~1\MICROS~1\VBA\VBA7\VBE7.DLL`.

Comment: Try to replace the Normal template `Normal.dotm` found in folder `C:\Users\user name\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Templates`. If this doesn't help, uninstall Office again, run the [clean uninstall Office tool](https://aka.ms/diag_officeuninstall) and reinstall Office.

Comment: You don't indicate which version `Avira Free Antivirus` you are running.  The fact your previous installation was not a "clean install" does not matter.  There is no difference outside between an installation that was upgraded from Windows 8.1 to Windows 10 and a clean installation of Windows 10.

Comment: @Ramhound Edited. _There is no difference outside between an installation that was upgraded from Windows 8.1 to Windows 10 and a clean installation of Windows 10._ Theoretically true, but perhaps there's some DLL that was installed while the computer was running Windows 8 that enabled this setup to worl; and is no longer necessary under Windows 10, and was therefore not installed this time around.

Comment: Maybe disabling virus protection isn't enough. Can you try to uninstall Avira, restart pc and open Vba editor after? That could help to decide whether the problem is really related to antivirus.

Comment: @harrymc Tried both, without success.

Comment: Very very strange. Another test is to boot in Safe Mode to check if VBA is blocked by some third-party product, and if that works then find out which one. The ultimate test is reinstalling a fresh version of Windows and Office, but no other product or antivirus. If VBA then works, install other products until it breaks again. If it doesn't, you need to check the installation options of Office that you are disabling (you can also check it right now by doing Change of Office in Programs & Features).

Comment: @harrymc _check the installation options of Office_ if VBA is not installed? But the VBA editor comes up eventually, just not really usable.

Comment: That comment was just in case that a non-standard installation option caused VBA to malfunction.

Comment: @harrymc I've not installed Outlook; could that be related?

Comment: I have selectively installed Office before with never a problem, but everything is possible. You could try to install Office with all defaults to verify if this works (only redoing what you already did before is not going to change anything).

Comment: Are there any errors or warnings in the Application or System event logs around the time of your attempts to start VBA?

Comment: Any news on the problem?

Comment: @harrymc Some updates.

Comment: It's strange that an exclusive access is requested for the VBA files, and also that there are already readers. My feeling is that some software is locking those files. I would still advice booting in Safe Mode as test, and also using Process Explorer to search in normal boot for all processes that are using these files.

Comment: @harrymc I already tried booting in Safe Mode; Word opens briefly then closes, because the activation can't be detected.

Answer (score 1):

## Verify or install the latest updates

You might have to set Windows Update to automatically download and install recommended updates. Installing any important, recommended, and optional updates can frequently correct problems by replacing out-of-date files and fixing vulnerabilities. To install the latest Microsoft Office updates, see [Update Office and your computer with Microsoft Update](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/install-office-updates-2ab296f3-7f03-43a2-8e50-46de917611c5?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US).

For list of the latest Office updates, see [Office Updates](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/officeupdates/office-updates-msi?redirectSourcePath=%252farticle%252fa118ec61-f007-492f-bfa5-5a6f764d5471). If your issue is not resolved after you install the latest Windows and Office updates, go to method 2.

It's a good idea to make sure that your computer has the latest updates installed for Windows. Updates often fix software problems. Before you use any of the following methods, try first to install updates. After you install the updates, restart your computer, and then start Word.

## Troubleshoot problems that occur when you start Word

> **Important**
> Follow the steps in this section carefully. Serious problems might occur if you modify the registry incorrectly. Before you modify it, [back up the registry for restoration](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/322756/how-to-back-up-and-restore-the-registry-in-windows) in case problems occur.

Here are troubleshooting methods you should try:

Method 1: Insert your document into another file
Method 2: Start Word by using the /a switch
Method 3: Delete the Word Data registry subkey
Method 4: Delete the Word Options registry key
Method 5: Replace the Normal.dot or Normal.dotm global template file
Method 6: Disable the Startup folder add-ins
Method 7: Delete the COM add-ins registry keys
Method 8: Change the default printer

Follow details in [MSDN](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/921541/how-to-troubleshoot-problems-that-occur-when-you-start-or-use-word).

Answer (score 0):

## Verify Permissions and File Access

Since the error suggests that a file cannot be created/written to/read, I would start by using [procmon](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon) by Sysinternals to reveal any read/write errors or access denied errors by the office application. It’s possible that a folder in the required path is missing, or that file permissions are not set as expected.

This may also reveal whether certain registry keys are missing or have incorrect permissions.

## Ensure UAC is Not Blocking Startup

You should try running the application after turning off UAC temporarily if you haven’t already. UAC could be prevent other processes from spawning despite running the original app as Administrator.

## Check Event Logs for Warnings and Errors

Check the **System**, **Application** and **Security** event logs for errors and warnings around the time of your attempts. If they are present and repeat at each attempt to start VBA, add them to your question as further evidence.

## Start in a Fresh Environment

Create a new user account with local Administrator rights. Log on with the new account and try starting the VBA editor. This provides a ‘clean’ environment based on the local default user profile, which helps determine if user profile corruption is the cause.

Comment: You should add`Applications and Services Logs > Microsoft Office`to the event logs

Comment: @ComputerVersteher I wasn't aware of this additional location, it's not present on my machine. I do have `Microsoft Office Alerts` but AFAIK this only logs the messages that were displayed to the user. Do you have a reference for this?

Comment: I guess they are the same, On Win10 x64 Office 2007 I have `Microsoft Office Diagnostics`/ `Sessions`under`Applications and Services Logs` and there you can find usefull information (e.g ms-access query error msgs), I wasn't aware of that

Comment: Nothing in **System**, **Application**, and **Security**; and **Applications and Services Logs > Microsoft Office** shows an event for opening VBA from Word, but for no other application. Edited into the question.

Comment: I've updated the question with results from procmon.

Comment: Turning off UAC doesn't help; edited question.

Comment: I’ve updated my answer with another step to try - new user profile.

Answer (score 0):

Since this strange problem arrives on more than one computer,
even in fact on all your computers, this relates more to your installation
than to a bug in Office.

The problem might be that your company is installing Windows Update patches
selectively (MSUS), or an unfortunate choice of installation options, or some
software product you have installed on all your computers (primary suspect
is always the security software).

Some tests that you can make are booting in Safe Mode to disable all third-party
software, or to use
[Process Explorer](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer)
to check which process is locking `VBE7.DLL` and `VBE6EXT.OLB`.

Last test is to make a clean installation of Windows 10 and only of Office,
using default installation settings, then running repeatedly Windows Update
until it finds no more updates. You can do this in a virtual machine to simplify.

Whatever you will find, I believe that this problem relates to
your installation methodology or software.

Comment: Ahem. This issue only arises on a single computer, the only computer I currently have running Windows and Office 2010.

Comment: Didn't you say something about other computers? In any case, my advice still applies.

Comment: I see that Safe Mode Boot did not fix the problem, so it must be in relation to the way you install Office. Safe Mode only disables Windows-level products, so any plugins added to Office will still work and may cause problems.

Comment: This is a clean install of Office; no addins. Also, I've added some details -- it seems that Word can't `CreateFileMapping` using the long paths, but it succeeds with the the DOS names.

Comment: Might the problem be simply the need for increased [Maximum Path Length Limitation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/fileio/naming-a-file#maximum-path-length-limitation)? In `HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\FileSystem` REG_DWORD `LongPathsEnabled`.

Comment: The current value is set to `0`. Is the appropriate value `1`?

Comment: Yes, reboot if no immediate change.

Comment: I tried setting that registry key to `1` and rebooting; no difference.

Comment: So back to finding out what is special about this computer.

Comment: I used Process Explorer; the only process locking these files is Word.

Comment: Is this worth a reinstallation? Or trying in a new virtual machine?

Comment: I did try to reinstall Office. Reinstalling Windows is probably not worth it ATM. I may have no other choice, but it's not something I can do right now.

Comment: One more: Did I understand correctly that this failure depends on the length of the path of the document? Does a short path work? I know that VBA dates from ancient times, so it is possible that the code was never updated as Windows evolved beyond its primitive beginnings into Windows NT. For example, [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14720710/is-there-a-way-for-dirpath-in-vba-to-handle-strings-longer-than-260) where nobody managed to use long paths in VBA.

Comment: I've tested primarily in new documents, which don't really have a path.

Comment: Then this is caused by your installation on this computer, which I have no way to analyze.

Answer (score 0):

Once a time, I encountered the same error while using both MS Office 2016 and MS Office 2003 on the same computer, I searched a lot and found one thing that was similar to not having enough permission to do so, even on the administrator account.

As you said, you are using **Windows 10**. Open task manager, and check **Office Source Engine** status, if it is stopped then run it, but if you can't run it and try Ccleaner and clean up the registry and restart the computer.

Comment: Office Source Engine was indeed stopped, but I can start it successfully. However, starting it doesn't help -- the VBA editor still won't open properly.

Comment: Have you cleared registry errors, using any software of your choice? I did it with [Ccleaner](https://filehippo.com/download_ccleaner/)

Comment: Registry cleaners are not generally recognized as being useful, and CCleaner has been reported to have user-hostile behavior (e.g., spying on you, installing updates automatically without your consent, refusing to exit when you want it to).